# How to get Mongoose document data

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get all documents from a mongoose model (List), and get a certain bit of data from each document (name).

This is my best attempt:

```
List.find({}, function(err, data) { console.log(err, data.name); });
```

Just logging "data", rather than "data.name" gives me the whole document, which I'm not after.

Logging "data.name" gives me "undefined".

Comment: Is your `whole document` include `name`?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand you. When I log the whole document, I do get "name" as one of the fields.

(Sorry for the late reply, I thought I'd get an email notification but I didn't)